# GraphQL arguments to connection sub results

Tags: graphql

I'm need help passing arguments to collections/connections/arrays in GraphQL syntax.

I'm just learning it, playing with the SWAPI at http://graphql.org/swapi-graphql/

I can pass an id argument to a single type, like this:

```
query getANewHope {
  film(id: "ZmlsbXM6MQ==") {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to query the results of a collection/connection

```
query starships {
  allStarships(id: "c3RhcnNoaXBzOjI=") { # this doesn't work
    edges {
      node(id: "c3RhcnNoaXBzOjI=") { # ...nor this.
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to query collections because, I'd like to connect the two ideas like "All Starfighter type ships in A New Hope"?

```
query filmStarships {
  film(id: "ZmlsbXM6MQ==") {
    title
    starshipConnection { #How to limit this?  I can't use (starshipClass: "Starfighter") here...
      edges {
        node { # ...nor here..
          starshipClass # ...nor here.
        }
      }
    }
  }
}




query starships2 {
  starship (id:  "c3RhcnNoaXBzOjI=") { # This doesn't work either
    id # even without an arugment abovce, it says "Unknown argument \"id\" on field \"node\" of type \"StarshipsEdge\"."
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments like you're asking for have to be implemented in the schema. The SWAPI does does not expose an argument to filter by `starshipClass`. Click `Docs` on the top right of the GraphiQL window to explore the provided schema.

If you are implementing your own schema it would be very easy to add a filter on `starshipClass` in the resolvers.